# react-transition-group & react-router refNode

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-transition-group

I'm using react-transition-group to animate transtitions between pages in react-router.

When i don't use nodeRef={nodeRef} animation works fine but I get this error:

"findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here: fb.me/react-strict-mode-find-node"

When I use nodeRef={nodeRed} animation does't work but I don't get an error.

How to do it to not get an error and have working animation

````
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { TransitionGroup, CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

const nodeRef = useRef(null)

       <Route render={({location}) => (

       <TransitionGroup>
         <CSSTransition nodeRef={nodeRef} key={location.key} timeout={2000} classNames="fade">

         <Switch location={location}>

           <Route path='/' exact component={Home}/>
           <Route path='/about' component={About}/>
           <Route path='/skills' component={Skills}/>
           <Route path='/projects' component={Projects}/>
           <Route path='/contact' component={Contact}/>

         </Switch>

         </CSSTransition>
     </TransitionGroup>

   )} />

   </Router>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this issue as well. Then I found this page in the react-transition-group docs that basically suggests you avoid using `TransitionGroup` entirely when dealing with `react-router`, and just wrap all of your components rendered by a Route inside of `CSSTransition` directly. Link is here: http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/with-react-router/

In case the link breaks in the future, here's the relevant bit:

> People often want to animate route transitions, which can result in
> delightful UX when used in moderation. The first instict might be to
> use wrap all routes in `TransitionGroup`, but that approach requires
> hacks and falls apart easily when used with trickier components of
> React Router like `Redirect`. You should use `CSSTransition` for each
> route and manage their in prop on their own.
>
> The main challenge is the exit transition because React Router changes
> to a new route instantly, so we need to keep the old route around long
> enough to transition out of it. Fortunately, `Route`'s children prop
> also accepts a function, which should not be confused with the render
> prop! Unlike the render prop, children function runs whether the route
> is matched or not. React Router passes the object containing a match
> object, which exists if the route matches, otherwise it's null. This
> enables us to manage the in prop of `CSSTransition` based on the
> presence of match.

There's a demo app as well, I won't share it all but here's the relevant portion as far as `<Route>` is concerned:

```
<Route key={path} exact path={path}>
  {({ match }) => (
    <CSSTransition
      in={match != null}
      timeout={300}
      classNames="page"
      unmountOnExit
    >
      <div className="page">
        <Component />
      </div>
    </CSSTransition>
  )}
</Route>
```

Answer (score -3):

I think this is your error:

```
nodeRef = useRef(null)
```

Should be:

```
nodeRef = React.useRef(null)
```